# Install Beautiful Soup using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, pip

I am trying to install [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup) using `pip` in Python 2.7. I keep getting an error message and can't understand why.

I followed the instructions to install pip, which was installed to the following directory: `c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`. Then I tried adding it to the path, and running the `pip install package` command.

I tried it two different ways:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\pip.exe')
pip install beautifulsoup4

import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Scripts')
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Both give me this error message:

```
>>> pip install beautifulsoup4
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The shell is highlighting the word "install" and saying that it's invalid syntax.

What's going on?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

`pip` is a *command line tool*, not Python syntax.

In other words, run the command in your console, *not* in the Python interpreter:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

You may have to use the full path:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or even

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install beautifulsoup4
```

Windows will then execute the `pip` program and *that* will use Python to install the package.

Another option is to use the Python `-m` command-line switch to run the `pip` module, which then operates exactly like the `pip` command:

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or

```
python.exe -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Sometimes, you might get a '**Permission Denied**' error in which case, you will need to add '**sudo**' before the command to run it as a super-user.
Thus, the command would be as follows :-
`sudo pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: @NamanSancheti that is usually an indication that you want to create a virtualenv instead and install into there instead.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I am still active here on SO, I did not feel that that comment needed adding to my answer.

Comment: For everyone else - the comment was that you can use the **--user** argument to avoid sudo, eg: `pip install --user beautifulsoup4`  - you can reproduce this using an Amazon Linux AMI - it's not necessarily related to a VirtualEnv, just running vanilla scripts you can encounter this error.

Answer (score 5):

The easy method that will work even in a corrupted setup environment is:

To download ez_setup.py and run it using the command line,

```
python ez_setup.py
```

#### Output

> Extracting in c:\uu\uu\appdata\local\temp\tmpjxvil3 
> Now working in c:\u\u\appdata\local\temp\tmpjxvil3\setuptools-5.6 
> Installing Setuptools

#### Run

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

#### Output

> Downloading/unpacking beautifulsoup4 
> Running setup.py ... egg_info for package 
> Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4 
> Running setup.py install for beautifulsoup4 
> Successfully installed beautifulsoup4 
> Cleaning up...

Bam! Done.

Comment: and import it as: " import bs4"

Answer (score 4):

```
import os

os.system("pip install beautifulsoup4")

or

import subprocess

exe = subprocess.Popen("pip install beautifulsoup4")

exe_out = exe.communicate()

print(exe_out)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one version of Python installed, run the respective *pip* command.

For example, for Python 3.6 run the following

```
pip3.6 install beautifulsoup4
```

To check the available command/version of *pip* and *python* on **Mac** run

```
ls /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: excellent! didn't now for Py3 you use pip3, thanks