# regex for string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following string and i would like to extract the value of the field

```
<td class="label" width="150"">State</td><td width="" class="field">Approved&nbsp;</td>
```

in this case it should be Approved

Also sometime the input can be like this

```
<td class="label" width="150"">Type</td><td width="" class="field">Technical&nbsp;Document&nbsp;</td>
```

which shd result in Technical Document

Sometimes it can be

```
 <td class="label" width="150"">Title</td><td width="" class="field">Reversal Plate</td>
```

In this case it will be Reversal Plate

How can we write a regular expression for such string.

Comment: You look like you're trying to parse HTML with regex. Would you prefer better options?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex for this, you should use some HTML/XML parser, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser') #`s` being your string.
for td in soup.findAll('td',class_="field"):
    print(td.get_text())
```

The above would get correct results for both your examples.

Demo -

```
>>> s = """<td class="label" width="150"">State</td><td width="" class="field">Approved&nbsp;</td>"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
>>> for td in soup.findAll('td',class_="field"):
...     print(td.get_text())
...
Approved 
>>> s = """<td class="label" width="150"">Type</td><td width="" class="field">Technical&nbsp;Document&nbsp;</td>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
>>> for td in soup.findAll('td',class_="field"):
...     print(td.get_text())
...
Technical Document
```

Comment: I would like to try out the available options, is it possible to get it using regex?

Comment: @RidhiJain You can look at the other answer, but please note it will only work in very very specific cases. So if you are 100% sure that the three examples you gave are the only cases you want to find , you can use that. it would stop working if there is a small scape between `"` and `>` in the tag. But most regex solutions you are going to get would be like that.

Comment: how to install beautiful Soup....i m new to python, how to check wat version i m running

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.version)` should give you your current python version. You can install beautiful soup from `pip` using `pip install beautifulsoup` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957194/install-beautiful-soup-using-pip This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Anand S Kumar you don't have to use `regex`, using `Beautifulsoup` is faster. However, since you asked for a `regex` solution, you can use the code below:

```
import re
s = '<td class="label" width="150"">State</td><td width="" class="field">Approved&nbsp;</td>'
m = re.compile('"field">(.*)<')
print (m.search(s).group(1))
```

Output:

```
Approved&nbsp;
```

This `regex` solution will match anything that is inside the `class="field">....</td>`