# Python: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pydev

This might be a super newbie question but I am trying to import BeautifulSoup to my python project:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

but I am getting this error:

```
import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
```

From what I am reading I have to install it make a child folder for it? If so why do my other imports such as import urllib.request work without installation and this one doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install beautifulsoup4`? Beautiful Soup is an external module whereas urllib is from the standard library of Python, so you don't have to install it.

Comment: Did you pip install beautifulsoup4 from the command line? See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957194/install-beautiful-soup-using-pip)

Answer (score 1):

Python comes with a default set of modules - you can see that `urllib` is included with your installation of Python by [looking at the list of default modules on this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

[You should follow these instructions to download and use `pip`](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip), the Python package manager and installer, to get and install the `BeautifulSoup` module.

Comment: just to add, newer versions of python ship with pip, so you may not need to install it.